# Edit Visio custom shape data from Powershell

Tags: powershell, visio

How can I edit Visio custom shape data from a Powershell script?

I have figured out how to open the document and how to loop the objects in a sheet, but how do I access the the shape data?

```
$Visio = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$Doc=$Visio.Documents.Open('c:\TestVisio.vsdx')
$Page=$Doc.Pages('TestPage')
....
```

Comment: Just in case, do you know the object model is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768546.aspx)?

Comment: Thank's! If I have a custom shape data "Mydata" with value 123 on some object, how do get (or update) that value using this document - what is the syntax?

Comment: Never Mind, I solved it, can now create, update, and connect obejcts dynamically from PS :)

Comment: Can you share how did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot about this post. I googled for it, here is a small snippet to get you started:

$doc is your Visio file, $TabName is the name of the tab you are using.

```
    $page=$doc.Pages("$TabName")
    $ObjectName='Box1'

    # Find Visio object
    foreach($shape in $page.Shapes)
    {
        if($shape.CellExists("Prop.Row_1.Value", 0))
        {
            IF ($shape.Cells("Prop.Row_1.Value").FormulaU -eq "`"$ObjectName`"")
            {
                $NewShape = $shape
                $ShapeFound = 1
                break
            }
        }
    }
```